# continuous representation of $G_K$ as $\rho: G_K \to GL(V)$

Tags: smooth-functions, galois-representations

Let $K$ be a finite extension of the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and let $G_K:=Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}_p)$ is the Galois group.
Now if we consider the continuous representation of $G_K$ as $\rho: G_K \to GL(V)$, where $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

**My question:**

What topology is there in the codomain $GL(V)$ so that $\rho$ is continuous?

Offcourse if i give indiscrete topology, then it continuous. But what is the topology in the above case?

Comment: If $\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb Q_p)$ is a finite group, then it must have the discrete topology. Hence, any representation of $G_K$ is continuous.

Comment: @Mathmo123, thanks. Now for $K/\mathbb{Q}_<\infty$,  $G_K:=\varprojlim Gal(\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p/K) \twoheadrightarrow Gal(L/K), \ \forall L/K< \infty$. Then $G_K \cong \varprojlim Gal(L/K)  \subset \prod_{L} Gal(L/K)$. Now as you said each $Gal$ being finite has discrete topology. So $G_K$ must have product topology, at least from the last sentence. Is it?

Comment: Something is a bit off from your notation. in any case, $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}_p/K)$ has the profinite topology. A basis of open subgroups is $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb Q}_p/L)$ where $L$ is a finite Galois extension of $K$.

Comment: Based on your recent questions, it seems like you're trying to run before you can walk: $p$-adic Hodge theory is extremely complicated, and is not something you should attempt until you have a solid understanding of the general theory of Galois representations. I'd recommend looking at [Taylor's ICM paper](https://www.math.ias.edu/~rtaylor/longicm02.pdf) and the materials from [Kevin Buzzard's recent course at MSRI](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~buzzard/MSRI/).

Comment: @Mathmo123, you are right. But still i am reading the subject p-adic Hodge theory but I have less knowledge of Galois representation theory. You are exactly right. But I hope I can (taking time) with help from others because the subject makes me interested unknowingly.